# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I created a method to get data from table, but it gives me error as stated in the title. Before posting here,I have read many ways from various websites including stackoverflow but it did not help me.

Below is my method.

```
    public SqlDataReader GetCustomer()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        _conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT CustName, CustNationality FROM Customer";
        using (_conn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _conn))
            {
                _conn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                _conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

and I am calling the method as;

```
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        cmboBoxClient.Items.Add("");
        reader = connect.GetCustomer() as SqlDataReader;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            cmboBoxClient.Items.Add(reader["CustName"] + " " + reader["CustNationality"]);
        }
```

But gives me error, I tried in the method IEnumerable , but then it gave me error of conversion/cast. i.e IDataReader to SqlDataReader.
Later I read that this approach is not possible.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Return customer instance from `GetCustomer` method instead of returning reader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing connection before returning reader. You should keep connection open while you are using database cursor. So, returning reader is not best option, because you cannot dispose connection while its being used by caller. I suggest you to create strongly-typed class `Customer`

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
}
```

And fill list of customers inside your `GetCustomers` method (yes, your query returns many customers, not single one):

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT CustName, CustNationality FROM Customer";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))        
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            yield return new Customer {
                Name = (string)reader["CustName"],
                Nationality = (string)reader["CustNationality"]
            };
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow you automatically close connection when enumeration ends and keep caller code away from database details:

```
cmboBoxClient.Items.Add("");

foreach(var customer in connect.GetCustomers())
    cmboBoxClient.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}",customer.Name, customer.Nationality));
```

---

BTW [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) can do all querying and mapping for you. So that code will look like

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {                
        conn.Open();
        return conn.Query<Customer>("SELECT CustName, CustNationality FROM Customer");
    }
}
```

Yes, that's all you need.

Comment: *"because you cannot dispose connection while its being used by caller"*, yes you can, if you do `cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` when you dispose of the reader it closes the underlying connection. While it is not "disposeing" the connection the only thing disposing a connection does is close it (plus null out a few internal variables)

Comment: It was explanation of error OP has - currently he closes connection while its being used by caller. But anyway, thanks for pointing at `CommandBehavior` option

Comment: Ahh, sorry, misinterpreted the statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the connection, the reader is no longer valid to use.

You can move your reading logic (the loop that you have) inside the other method (i.e. `GetCustomer`) before you close the connection and before you dispose of the command.

Another solution would be to use a callback like this:

```
public void GetCustomer(Action<SqlDataReader> callback)
{
    var connString = "connection_string";

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    var _conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT CustName, CustNationality FROM Customer";
    using (_conn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _conn))
        {
            _conn.Open();
            using(reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                callback(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
connect.GetCustomer((reader =>
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cmboBoxClient.Items.Add(reader["CustName"] + " " + reader["CustNationality"]);
    }
}));
```

This allows you to make the `GetCustomer` method more generic. You can reuse it multiple times and each time you can use the reader differently.

You might want to use a better name for the method. For example, `ReadCustomers`.